# How to fetch SQLlite data in a shortest time possible

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sharedpreferences

I am trying to fetch a data from an Sqlite and bind it to a Recyclerview.The problem I am facing here is it is taking so long to get all the data from the database and add it to an Array List(I am using AsyncTask). I also have tried to fetch only the datas which matches to the text I am looking for,Still it takes long time. I tried to save the ArrayList in a SharedPreferences and use it when needed but I couldn't save ArrayList of a specific class to a shared Preference(it doesnt support).  which way can i solve this problem? 
   I apologize for my English.

Comment: Do you need to store all the information in memory all at once?  Or, could you stream it in chunks as you need it?

Comment: Could yo share your code

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I need to save all the information to the database once, because the app is designed to be used offline once it get the informations from a webservice

Comment: Try [TinyDB](https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo) to store anything using the SharedPrefences.

Comment: See if you want to do operations (SQL operation filter, groupBy) then you can use SQL, otherwise, I suggest to use SharedPreference with Gson compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'.

Comment: @KushaalSingla I added the library but it is not yet recognizing TinyDB

Comment: Check Room library